# Associating AutoComplete TextBox to Xml with WP7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, autocomplete

Is there a way to create an autocomplete textBox using data from a xml file with WP7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you read the XML file and use that data as the `ItemsSource` for the AutoCompleteBox.

It's not possible to pass raw XML, or the path to the file, to the AutoCompleteBox and have it automatically work out what to display.